# Find state from Area Code

Tags: formula, leads, automation, country-and-state, sales

Our leads come in with just a phone number. I am looking to populate a custom field for the Lead State based off of that area code. I have already added a custom formula field to populate the time zone based off of the area code but I cannot create a custom formula field to populate the State based off of the area code because the formula will exceed the character limit. I also created another custom formula field to extract just the area code from the lead phone field. How do I take what I have now to use the area code to populate the State abbreviation into another field?

Update 1: Here is what I have tried (this works, but need 4 workflow rules because character count on each is ~3600; when I only have 2 of the 4 activated, it works, but I cannot add a 3rd or 4th activated rule, will just return a Null answer)

```
IF(Lead_copied_area_code__c = 808 , "HI",
IF(Lead_copied_area_code__c = 907, "AK",
IF(Lead_copied_area_code__c = 334, "AL",
IF(Lead_copied_area_code__c = 251, "AL",...
```

Also tried:

```
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT( Lead_copied_area_code__c ) , "334:251:205:938:256") , "AL", 
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT( Lead_copied_area_code__c ) , "501:479:870") , "AR",
```

Comment: did you consider process builder or workflows to segment the problem down to sets of area codes (and hence bypass the formula size limit)?

Comment: If you have list of possible area code and state values, store them as custom setting. Use trigger to update lead by checking custom setting values.

Comment: @cropredy I tried a workflow rile with field update using this formula but it doesnt work: 
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT( Lead_copied_area_code__c ) , "334:251:205:938:256") , "AL", 
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT( Lead_copied_area_code__c ) , "501:479:870") , "AR", 
IF( CONTAINS(TEXT( Lead_copied_area_code__c ) , "684") , "AS", NULL)))

Comment: @Reshma How would I configure this?

Comment: Dennis - please use [edit] to amend your question with your WF solution. Debugging via comments is not practical. You will need multiple workflow rules to avoid the formula size restriction (or multiple PB decisionblocks|action groups

Comment: @cropredy please look at it now

Comment: a) Your CONTAINS expressions are backwards:  use `IF(CONTAINS('334:251...',TEXT(Lead_Copied_Area_Code__c),'AL',....`  b) you need to use [edit] and expose the WF entry criteria of each of the 4 WF rules - my suspicion  is you have some typo - you can verify this by testing each WF rule 1x1.

Comment: @cropredy the criteria is the same for each of the 4 WF Rules; Lead: Phone is not equal to null and Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited

Comment: Hmm. I would have used entry conditions that segmented the area codes for eastern us, central us, etc

Comment: So what is the next step? I have the area code and the time zone but still need to populate the State in a custom field for my sales reps.